# How to tell whether running in a browser or in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

What is the best way for Javascript code to tell whether it is running in a browser or in NodeJS?

I'm looking for something which will evaluate to a boolean.

Trying to access `window` and catching the exception seems rather clinky.  Is there a better way?

Comment: No exception involved; `nodal = (typeof window === 'undefined');`

Comment: Why don't you check process.version which in node gives the following output: { http_parser: '1.0',
  node: '0.10.4',
  v8: '3.14.5.8',
  ares: '1.9.0-DEV',
  uv: '0.10.3',
  zlib: '1.2.3',
  modules: '11',
  openssl: '1.0.1e' }

Comment: Here's the block we use for Node/AMD/Browser detection ([link](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4/blob/master/tv4.js#L10-L19)) - instead of a boolean (there are more than two kinds of setup), it calls the initialisation function in different configurations.

Comment: http://timetler.com/2012/10/13/environment-detection-in-javascript/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a cut down version of the [UMD method](https://github.com/umdjs/umd):

```
var isNode = (typeof exports === 'object') ? true: false;
```

Comment: Why return a bool for something that's going to evaluate to a bool anyway? `var isNode = typeof exports !== 'object';`

Comment: I think my version is clearer.

Comment: How can you be sure that in the future the 'exports' variable is not going to represent an object browser side?

Comment: The common "cast to boolean" operator (which is still unnecessary, but at least makes the booleanness clear) is `!!`.  `? true : false` is a strong code smell to most JavaScript devs.

Comment: First I've heard of that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var isNode = (typeof processs != 'undefined' && typeof process.versions != 'undefined' && typeof process.versions.node != 'undefined');
```

Comment: @BenFortune you are right: corrected.